# Unreal Engine 4 Crashes at Startup when Using Linux with (core dumped) Error

Tags: linux, runtime-error, unreal-engine4

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS on my computer. Today I thought I'd give Unreal Engine a try and take a break from Blender Game Engine which is not quite as good looking. I waited a long time for the program to install but when I go to run it the program crashes. The splash screen shows up for a few seconds and then closes immediately. I ran this in my terminal and I get this extremely large error:

```
Pooling OS allocations (pool size: 1408 MB, maximum allocations: 9502).
Using binned2.
Increasing per-process limit of core file size to infinity.
- Existing per-process limit (soft=18446744073709551615, hard=18446744073709551615) is enough for us (need only 18446744073709551615)
LogInit:Display: Running engine without a game
LogPlatformFile: Not using cached read wrapper
LogInit:Display: RandInit(-1034489373) SRandInit(-1034489373).
LogTaskGraph: Started task graph with 5 named threads and 6 total threads with 1 sets of task threads.
LogStats: Stats thread started at 0.058173
LogInit: Using libcurl 7.48.0-DEV
LogInit:  - built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
LogInit:  - supports SSL with OpenSSL/1.0.2h
LogInit:  - supports HTTP deflate (compression) using libz 1.2.8
LogInit:  - other features:
LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_SSL
LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_LIBZ
LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_IPV6
LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_ASYNCHDNS
LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_LARGEFILE
LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_TLSAUTH_SRP
LogInit:  Libcurl: checking if '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt' exists
LogInit:  Libcurl: checking if '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' exists
LogInit:  CurlRequestOptions (configurable via config and command line):
LogInit:  - bVerifyPeer = true  - Libcurl will verify peer certificate
LogInit:  - bUseHttpProxy = false  - Libcurl will NOT use HTTP proxy
LogInit:  - bDontReuseConnections = false  - Libcurl will reuse connections
LogInit:  - CertBundlePath = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  - Libcurl will set CURLOPT_CAINFO to it
LogInit: Build: ++UE4+Release-4.16-CL-0
LogInit: Engine Version: 4.16.2-0+++UE4+Release-4.16
LogInit: Compatible Engine Version: 4.16.0-0+++UE4+Release-4.16
LogInit: Net CL: 0
LogDevObjectVersion: Number of dev versions registered: 16
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Blueprints (B0D832E4-1F89-4F0D-ACCF-7EB736FD4AA2): 9
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Build (E1C64328-A22C-4D53-A36C-8E866417BD8C): 0
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Core (375EC13C-06E4-48FB-B500-84F0262A717E): 2
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Editor (E4B068ED-F494-42E9-A231-DA0B2E46BB41): 17
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Framework (CFFC743F-43B0-4480-9391-14DF171D2073): 23
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Mobile (B02B49B5-BB20-44E9-A304-32B752E40360): 0
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Networking (A4E4105C-59A1-49B5-A7C5-40C4547EDFEE): 0
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Online (39C831C9-5AE6-47DC-9A44-9C173E1C8E7C): 0
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Physics (78F01B33-EBEA-4F98-B9B4-84EACCB95AA2): 0
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Platform (6631380F-2D4D-43E0-8009-CF276956A95A): 0
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Rendering (12F88B9F-8875-4AFC-A67C-D90C383ABD29): 15
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-Sequencer (7B5AE74C-D270-4C10-A958-57980B212A5A): 4
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-VR (D7296918-1DD6-4BDD-9DE2-64A83CC13884): 0
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-LoadTimes (C2A15278-BFE7-4AFE-6C17-90FF531DF755): 1
LogDevObjectVersion:   Private-Geometry (6EACA3D4-40EC-4CC1-B786-8BED09428FC5): 1
LogDevObjectVersion:   Dev-AnimPhys (29E575DD-E0A3-4627-9D10-D276232CDCEA): 3
LogInit: Compiled (64-bit): Jul 30 2017 00:37:10
LogInit: Compiled with Clang: 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
LogInit: Build Configuration: Development
LogInit: Branch Name: ++UE4+Release-4.16
LogInit: Command line: 
LogInit: Base directory: /home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/
LogInit: Installed Engine Build: 0
LogInit: Presizing for max 8388607 objects, including 0 objects not considered by GC, pre-allocating 0 bytes for permanent pool.
LogInit: Object subsystem initialized
[2017.07.30-07.15.22:504][  0]LogInit: Initializing SDL.
[2017.07.30-07.15.22:504][  0]LogInit: Using SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:040][  0]LogInit: Initialized SDL 2.0.4 revision: 10374 (hg-10374:dccf51aee79b with EpicExtensions) (compiled against 2.0.4)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit: Display metrics:
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayWidth: 1366
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayHeight: 768
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayWorkAreaRect:
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:     Left=57, Top=30, Right=1366, Bottom=768
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:   VirtualDisplayRect:
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:     Left=57, Top=0, Right=2646, Bottom=1024
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:   TitleSafePaddingSize: X=0.000 Y=0.000
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:   ActionSafePaddingSize: X=0.000 Y=0.000
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:   Number of monitors: 2
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:     Monitor 0
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       Name: 0
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       ID: display0
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       NativeWidth: 1366
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       NativeHeight: 768
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       bIsPrimary: true
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:     Monitor 1
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       Name: DELL E176FP 17"
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       ID: display1
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       NativeWidth: 1280
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       NativeHeight: 1024
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:074][  0]LogInit:       bIsPrimary: false
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:075][  0]LogLinux: Selected Device Profile: [Linux]
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:075][  0]LogInit: Applying CVar settings loaded from the selected device profile: [Linux]
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:092][  0]LogInit: Linux hardware info:
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:092][  0]LogInit:  - we are the first instance of this executable
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:092][  0]LogInit:  - this process' id (pid) is 6595, parent process' id (ppid) is 28819
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:092][  0]LogInit:  - we are not running under debugger
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:092][  0]LogInit:  - machine network name is 'Ubuntu'
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:092][  0]LogInit:  - user name is 'caden' (caden)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  - we're logged in locally
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  - we're running with rendering
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  - CPU: GenuineIntel '       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz' (signature: 0x206A7)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  - Number of physical cores available for the process: 2
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  - Number of logical cores available for the process: 4
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  - Cache line size: 64
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  - Memory allocator used: binned2
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogLinux: Benchmarking clocks:
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogLinux:  - CLOCK_REALTIME (id=0) can sustain 38472263 (38472K, 38M) calls per second without zero deltas.
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogLinux:  - CLOCK_MONOTONIC (id=1) can sustain 45080582 (45081K, 45M) calls per second without zero deltas.
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogLinux:  - CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW (id=4) can sustain 9332722 (9333K, 9M) calls per second without zero deltas.
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogLinux:  - CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE (id=6) can sustain 123650347 (123650K, 124M) calls per second with 99.999790% zero deltas.
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogLinux: Selected clock_id 1 (CLOCK_MONOTONIC) since it is the fastest support clock without zero deltas.
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit: Linux-specific commandline switches:
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  -nodwarf (currently OFF): suppress parsing of DWARF debug info (callstacks will be generated faster, but won't have line numbers)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  -ansimalloc - use malloc()/free() from libc (useful for tools like valgrind and electric fence)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  -jemalloc - use jemalloc for all memory allocation
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  -binnedmalloc - use binned malloc  for all memory allocation
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  -httpproxy=ADDRESS:PORT - redirects HTTP requests to a proxy (only supported if compiled with libcurl)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  -reuseconn - allow libcurl to reuse HTTP connections (only matters if compiled with libcurl)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:093][  0]LogInit:  -virtmemkb=NUMBER - sets process virtual memory (address space) limit (overrides VirtualMemoryLimitInKB value from .ini)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:094][  0]LogInit:  - Physical RAM available (not considering process quota): 8 GB (7864 MB, 8052996 KB, 8246267904 bytes)
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:095][  0]LogInit: Using OS detected language (en-US).
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:096][  0]LogInit: Using OS detected locale (en-US).
[2017.07.30-07.15.23:105][  0]LogTextLocalizationManager: No specific localization for 'en-US' exists, so the 'en' localization will be used.
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:345][  0]LogInit:Error: _PlatformCreateOpenGLContextCore - Could not create OpenGL 4.3 context, SDL error: 'Could not create GL context: GLXBadFBConfig'
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:345][  0]LogRHI:Error: OpenGL 4.3 not supported by driver
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:346][  0]LogInit:Error: _PlatformCreateOpenGLContextCore - Could not create OpenGL 4.3 context, SDL error: 'Could not create GL context: GLXBadFBConfig'
Assertion failed: SharedContext.hGLContext [File:/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/OpenGLDrv/Private/Linux/OpenGLLinux.cpp] [Line: 250] 
[Callstack]  00  0x00007fc05c505ebf  FLinuxPlatformStackWalk::CaptureStackBackTrace(unsigned long long*, unsigned int, void*)
[Callstack]  01  0x00007fc05c3983b5  FGenericPlatformStackWalk::StackWalkAndDump(char*, unsigned long, int, void*)
[Callstack]  02  0x00007fc05c505d7b  FLinuxPlatformStackWalk::StackWalkAndDump(char*, unsigned long, int, void*)
[Callstack]  03  0x00007fc05c557b3c  FDebug::LogAssertFailedMessage(char const*, char const*, int, wchar_t const*, ...)
[Callstack]  04  0x00007fbfdc9c8661  FPlatformOpenGLDevice::FPlatformOpenGLDevice()
[Callstack]  05  0x00007fbfdc9c4c8b  FOpenGLDynamicRHI::FOpenGLDynamicRHI()
[Callstack]  06  0x00007fbfdc9c49f2  FOpenGLDynamicRHIModule::CreateRHI(ERHIFeatureLevel::Type)
[Callstack]  07  0x00007fc055b40399  PlatformCreateDynamicRHI()
[Callstack]  08  0x00007fc055b3fb8f  RHIInit(bool)
[Callstack]  09  0x0000000000419d64  FEngineLoop::PreInit(wchar_t const*) [/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Private/LaunchEngineLoop.cpp, line 1665]
[Callstack]  10  0x000000000042b5e8  GuardedMain(wchar_t const*) [/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Private/Launch.cpp, line 42]
[Callstack]  11  0x00007fc0513232e7  CommonLinuxMain(int, char**, int (*)(wchar_t const*))
[Callstack]  12  0x00007fc0503e9830  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fc0503e9830]
[Callstack]  13  0x0000000000416129  ./Engine/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor(_start+0x29) [0x416129]

[2017.07.30-07.15.25:404][  0]LogLinux:Error: appError called: Assertion failed: Assertion failed: SharedContext.hGLContext [File:/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/OpenGLDrv/Private/Linux/OpenGLLinux.cpp] [Line: 250] 


Signal 11 caught.
Malloc Size=131076 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=131092 
CommonLinuxCrashHandler: Signal=11
Malloc Size=65535 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=196655 
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:464][  0]LogLinux: === Critical error: ===
Unhandled Exception: SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to write memory at address 0x0000000000000003

[2017.07.30-07.15.25:464][  0]LogLinux: Assertion failed: Assertion failed: SharedContext.hGLContext [File:/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/OpenGLDrv/Private/Linux/OpenGLLinux.cpp] [Line: 250] 



[Callstack]  00  0x00007fc05c505ebf  FLinuxPlatformStackWalk::CaptureStackBackTrace(unsigned long long*, unsigned int, void*)
[Callstack]  01  0x00007fc05c3983b5  FGenericPlatformStackWalk::StackWalkAndDump(char*, unsigned long, int, void*)
[Callstack]  02  0x00007fc05c4aae11  FLinuxCrashContext::CaptureStackTrace()
[Callstack]  03  0x00007fc051322440  CommonLinuxCrashHandler(FGenericCrashContext const&)
[Callstack]  04  0x00007fc05c4ace3d  PlatformCrashHandler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
[Callstack]  05  0x00007fc0622d5390  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7fc0622d5390]
[Callstack]  06  0x00007fc05c38b1b4  FGenericPlatformMisc::RaiseException(unsigned int)
[Callstack]  07  0x00007fc05c4f72cb  FOutputDeviceLinuxError::Serialize(wchar_t const*, ELogVerbosity::Type, FName const&)
[Callstack]  08  0x00007fc05c5c0568  FOutputDevice::Logf(wchar_t const*, ...)
[Callstack]  09  0x00007fc05c55876a  FDebug::AssertFailed(char const*, char const*, int, wchar_t const*, ...)
[Callstack]  10  0x00007fbfdc9c869f  FPlatformOpenGLDevice::FPlatformOpenGLDevice()
[Callstack]  11  0x00007fbfdc9c4c8b  FOpenGLDynamicRHI::FOpenGLDynamicRHI()
[Callstack]  12  0x00007fbfdc9c49f2  FOpenGLDynamicRHIModule::CreateRHI(ERHIFeatureLevel::Type)
[Callstack]  13  0x00007fc055b40399  PlatformCreateDynamicRHI()
[Callstack]  14  0x00007fc055b3fb8f  RHIInit(bool)
[Callstack]  15  0x0000000000419d64  FEngineLoop::PreInit(wchar_t const*) [/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Private/LaunchEngineLoop.cpp, line 1665]
[Callstack]  16  0x000000000042b5e8  GuardedMain(wchar_t const*) [/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Private/Launch.cpp, line 42]
[Callstack]  17  0x00007fc0513232e7  CommonLinuxMain(int, char**, int (*)(wchar_t const*))
[Callstack]  18  0x00007fc0503e9830  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fc0503e9830]
[Callstack]  19  0x0000000000416129  ./Engine/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor(_start+0x29) [0x416129]

[2017.07.30-07.15.25:474][  0]LogExit: Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
Pooling OS allocations (pool size: 1408 MB, maximum allocations: 9502).
Using binned2.
LogPlatformFile: Not using cached read wrapper
LogInit:Display: RandInit(-1382111109) SRandInit(-1382111109).
LogTaskGraph: Started task graph with 4 named threads and 5 total threads with 1 sets of task threads.
LogInit: Build: ++UE4+Release-4.16-CL-0
LogInit: Engine Version: 4.16.2-0+++UE4+Release-4.16
LogInit: Compatible Engine Version: 4.16.0-0+++UE4+Release-4.16
LogInit: Net CL: 0
LogInit: Compiled (64-bit): Jul 29 2017 22:04:21
LogInit: Compiled with Clang: 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
LogInit: Build Configuration: Shipping
LogInit: Branch Name: ++UE4+Release-4.16
LogInit: Command line:  -Abslog=/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Saved/Logs/UE4-CRC.log /home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Saved/Crashes/crashinfo--pid-6595-00038F2E1907011E000F01DAC29A1C21/
LogInit: Base directory: /home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/
LogInit: Installed Engine Build: 1
LogInit: Presizing for max 100000 objects, including 0 objects not considered by GC, pre-allocating 0 bytes for permanent pool.
LogInit: Object subsystem initialized
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:600][  0]LogInit: Linux hardware info:
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:600][  0]LogInit:  - we are the first instance of this executable
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:600][  0]LogInit:  - this process' id (pid) is 7674, parent process' id (ppid) is 6595
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:600][  0]LogInit:  - we are not running under debugger
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:600][  0]LogInit:  - machine network name is 'Ubuntu'
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - user name is 'caden' (caden)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - we're logged in locally
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - we're running with rendering
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - CPU: GenuineIntel '       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz' (signature: 0x206A7)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - Number of physical cores available for the process: 2
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - Number of logical cores available for the process: 4
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - Cache line size: 64
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - Memory allocator used: binned2
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogLinux: Skipped benchmarking clocks because the engine is running in a standalone program mode - CLOCK_REALTIME will be used.
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit: Linux-specific commandline switches:
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  -nodwarf (currently OFF): suppress parsing of DWARF debug info (callstacks will be generated faster, but won't have line numbers)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  -ansimalloc - use malloc()/free() from libc (useful for tools like valgrind and electric fence)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  -jemalloc - use jemalloc for all memory allocation
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  -binnedmalloc - use binned malloc  for all memory allocation
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  -httpproxy=ADDRESS:PORT - redirects HTTP requests to a proxy (only supported if compiled with libcurl)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  -reuseconn - allow libcurl to reuse HTTP connections (only matters if compiled with libcurl)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  -virtmemkb=NUMBER - sets process virtual memory (address space) limit (overrides VirtualMemoryLimitInKB value from .ini)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:601][  0]LogInit:  - Physical RAM available (not considering process quota): 8 GB (7864 MB, 8052996 KB, 8246267904 bytes)
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:602][  0]LogUObjectArray: 146 objects as part of root set at end of initial load.
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:602][  0]LogUObjectAllocator: 24112 out of 0 bytes used by permanent object pool.
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:602][  0]LogUObjectArray: CloseDisregardForGC: 0/0 objects in disregard for GC pool
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:602][  0]LogInit: Using OS detected language ().
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:602][  0]LogInit: Using OS detected locale ().
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:602][  0]LogTextLocalizationManager: No localization for '' exists, so 'en' will be used for the language.
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:602][  0]LogTextLocalizationManager: No localization for '' exists, so 'en' will be used for the locale.
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:632][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CrashReportClientVersion=1.0
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:632][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CrashReportReceiver disabled
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:632][  0]CrashReportClientLog: DataRouterUrl: https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:633][  0]CrashReportClientLog: Initial state = Unknown UploadState value
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:633][  0]CrashReportClientLog: Initial state = Unknown UploadState value
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:634][  0]LogCrashDebugHelper: DepotName: //UE4/Release-4.16
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:634][  0]LogCrashDebugHelper: BuiltFromCL: 0
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:634][  0]LogCrashDebugHelper: EngineVersion: 4.16.2-0+++UE4+Release-4.16
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:634][  0]LogCrashDebugHelper: BuildVersion: ++UE4+Release-4.16-CL-0
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:634][  0]LogCrashDebugHelper:Warning: CrashDebugHelperConfig invalid
[2017.07.30-07.15.25:634][  0]LogCrashDebugHelper:Warning: PDB Cache disabled
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: Got 5 pending files to upload from 'crashinfo--pid-6595-00038F2E1907011E000F01DAC29A1C21'
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: State change from Ready to SendingFiles
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CompressAndSendData have 5 pending files
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CompressAndSendData compressing 11570 bytes ('/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Saved/Crashes/crashinfo--pid-6595-00038F2E1907011E000F01DAC29A1C21/UE4.log')
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CompressAndSendData compressing 4 bytes ('/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Saved/Crashes/crashinfo--pid-6595-00038F2E1907011E000F01DAC29A1C21/minidump.dmp')
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CompressAndSendData compressing 108 bytes ('/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Saved/Crashes/crashinfo--pid-6595-00038F2E1907011E000F01DAC29A1C21/CrashReportClient.ini')
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CompressAndSendData compressing 2114 bytes ('/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Saved/Crashes/crashinfo--pid-6595-00038F2E1907011E000F01DAC29A1C21/Diagnostics.txt')
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:605][  0]CrashReportClientLog: CompressAndSendData compressing 1916 bytes ('/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine/Saved/Crashes/crashinfo--pid-6595-00038F2E1907011E000F01DAC29A1C21/wermeta.xml')
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit: Using libcurl 7.48.0-DEV
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:  - built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:  - supports SSL with OpenSSL/1.0.2h
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:  - supports HTTP deflate (compression) using libz 1.2.8
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:  - other features:
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_SSL
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_LIBZ
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_IPV6
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_ASYNCHDNS
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_LARGEFILE
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:618][  0]LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_TLSAUTH_SRP
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]LogInit:  Libcurl: checking if '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt' exists
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]LogInit:  Libcurl: checking if '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' exists
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]LogInit:  CurlRequestOptions (configurable via config and command line):
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]LogInit:  - bVerifyPeer = true  - Libcurl will verify peer certificate
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]LogInit:  - bUseHttpProxy = false  - Libcurl will NOT use HTTP proxy
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]LogInit:  - bDontReuseConnections = false  - Libcurl will reuse connections
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]LogInit:  - CertBundlePath = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  - Libcurl will set CURLOPT_CAINFO to it
[2017.07.30-07.15.26:619][  0]CrashReportClientLog: Sending HTTP request: https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data?AppID=CrashReporter&AppVersion=4.16.2-0%2B%2B%2BUE4%2BRelease-4.16&AppEnvironment=Release&UploadType=crashreports&UserID=000222680a07161d00010101f6e9fcfd%7C%7Cbeafb12cd46b4779bc75dc6d0cf7d2b1
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:139][  0]CrashReportClientLog: OnProcessRequestComplete(), State=SendingFiles bSucceeded=1
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:139][  0]CrashReportClientLog: State change from SendingFiles to SendingFiles
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:139][  0]CrashReportClientLog: All uploads done
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:139][  0]CrashReportClientLog: State change from SendingFiles to Finished
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:608][  0]LogLinux: FLinuxPlatformMisc::RequestExit(0)
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:608][  0]LogGenericPlatformMisc: FPlatformMisc::RequestExit(0)
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:640][  0]CrashReportClientLog: Final state (Receiver) = Finished
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:640][  0]CrashReportClientLog: Final state (Receiver) = Unknown UploadState value
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:641][  0]LogExit: Preparing to exit.
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:643][  0]LogObj: Freed 0b from 0 cluster array pools.
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:643][  0]LogExit: Object subsystem successfully closed.
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:644][  0]LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module HTTP (8)
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:679][  0]LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module SSL (7)
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:681][  0]LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CrashDebugHelper (4)
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:684][  0]LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CoreUObject (2)
[2017.07.30-07.15.27:685][  0]LogExit: Exiting.
Engine crash handling finished; re-raising signal 11 for the default handler. Good bye.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Building_On_Linux) to install Unreal Engine.

Comment: The log output has a clearcut lead: sdl error caused by unsupported opengl version. Try to update GPU driver and test your SDL lib.

Comment: My GPU only supports up to 3.3. Intel HD 3000. I'm sure there's a way to make Unreal think it's running in 4.3 though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Unreal Engine will crash if it doesn't have the right to write in `Editor/`, in your case `/home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine`.

You can try to start UnrealEngine with super user permissions (`sudo`) or `chmod` your folder with write access (`chmod 766 /home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine`).

Comment: When I did this it said that it refused to run with root privileges and the "chmod" did not seem to work sadly. ;(

Comment: What is the error message you get when trying to run it with root privileges ?

Comment: Otocat I get this:

`caden@Ubuntu:~/UnrealEngine$ sudo ./Engine/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor
[sudo] password for caden: 
Refusing to run with the root privileges.
caden@Ubuntu:~/UnrealEngine$`

Comment: Then I don't know, sorry. You could try to recursively change the rights of the folder but if it doesn't work, you should open an issue on the Github page.  You can try this : `chmod -R 766 /home/caden/UnrealEngine/Engine`

Comment: I think I noticed something about OpenGl version in the error as that part was red in the error. Maybe if I could trick it into thinking that it had OpenGl 4.3 it would work. How would one go about doing that then? Unity seems to work with OpenGl 3.3 and my GPU only supports 3.1. I don't see why Unreal won't work. By the way I love how awesome Unity looks, but I have no idea how to import BGE code from logic bricks to Unity so I'd rather use something with logic bricks. (Also Unity doesn't model?)

Comment: since when is Stackoverflow a microsoft forum? "run as Admin" has literally never been anything even remotely resembling a good idea on any unix.

Comment: Worked on my ubuntu 22 with unreal 5.1